# Buttons on externally loaded HTML files will not work

Tags: javascript, document-ready

I am using AJAX to load html files. Each html file has a vote up and vote down button.

The script that runs these two buttons are in a `document.ready` function in the main(index) html file.

When I directly insert the html into the main file, the `document.ready` function works.
But when I ajax load the html files, the contents of the `document.ready` function will not run.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your elements that gets loaded with ajax don't get binded to the events that where defined in document.ready because they did not exist when the document was ready.

You will need to use either **live** or **on**.

for example:

```
$('#buttonLoadedUsingAjax').live('click', function() {});
```

or if you are using jquery >1.7:

```
$(document).on("click", "#buttonLoadedUsingAjax", function(){ });
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your script that binds event handlers to your buttons is run *before* the buttons exist, newly added buttons won't have any event handlers.

What you can do is attach the event handler to a parent element of the buttons and then use the event object's target property to figure out if a button was clicked. That will ensure dynamically generated buttons also work.

If you're using jQuery you can use its on() method.

Answer (score 0):

When you load them with Ajax the function has *already* run. There is nothing happening that would make it run again.

Use [event delegation](http://icant.co.uk/sandbox/eventdelegation/) instead of binding the event handlers directly to the elements.